# Installation Guzzle in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle

how to Install Guzzle into Laravel 5?
I'm using laravel for my project, but I need library like guzzle to made me easy using curl in laravel. Any Body can help?

Answer (score 36):

Open a terminal, change into your laravel projects root dir and type

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Alternatively, you can add

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle":"*"
```

to your composer.json file's require section and run composer update.

Comment: how to implement guzzle as library or helper?

Comment: implementation, and calling into controller

Comment: @baao this should be updated to `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` -  since `composer require guzzle/guzzle` has been abandoned - see https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: I'm banging my head here... I'm getting

Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\HttpFoundationFactory' not found

Answer (score 9):

Via composer, cd into your laravel's project root directory, then

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

That's much it. Now guzzle is installed and ready to use.

Answer (score 3):

Add into composer.json requirements

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.*"
```

(5.* is Guzzle version, it could be change see more in guzzle github profile)

after editing run:

```
composer update
```

For more, see [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

Answer (score 2):

Since **Guzzle** is a generic PHP package and not specifically built for **Laravel**, it is a little bit confusing to Laravel users because you cannot use the class function "statically".

To install and use Guzzle in **Laravel 5** (I use it in Laravel 5.7),

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

You should then see **guzzlehttp** folder in **vendor** folder.

To use it, you can

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
...
public function testGuzzle()
{
    $client = new GuzzleClient();
    ...
}
```

If you do not want to import the namespace, you can also directly use it as below

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

As mentioned before, you cannot use it "statically"

```
GuzzleClient::request('GET', 'https://api.xxxx'); // this will throw you error.
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily accomplished by using the following repo
https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun

I believe the above link will have no issue with guzzlehttp 5.3 ~ 6.0

However if you are using Oauth with guzzle version above 6.0,
compare "/composer.json", "/src/Bogardo/Mailgun/Mailgun/MailgunApi.php" files between above link and below.
https://github.com/milocosmopolitan/Mailgun

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `composer.json` file in require:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"
```

save and then update your composer.