# Why I can't import Guzzle into my Laravel project using Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, guzzle

I am pretty new in **PHP** and **Laravel** and I am finding some difficulties trying to add **Guzzle** library (can I call it library in PHP slang, I came from Java...).

So I followed the suggestion of this SO post: [Installation Guzzle in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741347/installation-guzzle-in-laravel-5)

I have added this dependency into my **composer.json** file: "guzzle/guzzle":"*"

I have added it into this section of the original file (generated by Laravel):

```
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
    "guzzle/guzzle":"*"
},
```

I don't know if it is the right location.

Then I performed the **composer update** statment into my shell (from the root directory of my project) and I obtain this output:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Betrivius/WorkSpace/betriviusExtranet (master)
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled class file has been removed.
```

I see no error so I think that it is successfully completed.

The problem is that I can't find these dependency into my project and when before a class definitio I try to use it:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

I obtain this error message:

```
Undefine namespace
Referenced namespace is not found
```

In the specific I obtain an error message on these 4 red namespaces:

[image]

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: > Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.

Answer (score 3):

As stated, you should use `guzzlehttp/guzzle`, instead of `guzzle/guzzle`.

If you really need to use `guzzle/guzzle`, you can import it via `Guzzle` namespace, not `GuzzleHttp`, which is reserved for new version.

Answer (score 2):

> guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead

Use guzzlehttp/guzzle